# Advanced interface types for maps (objects) in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, proxy

I am creating a proxy-based system to intercept all reads/writes to a certain model. I am having problems, however, with creating the inerface types the system represents.

The system will, on a read or write to the model, intercept the read/write with a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and create new proxies accordingly to be able to intercept all future read/write operations. The root (let's call it `root`) proxy is cast to a type the proxy represents. This may be, for example:

```
interface Root {
    foo: string;
    bar: Map<OtherType>;
}
```

where

```
interface Map<T> {
    [key: string]: T | T[] | (obj: T) => string;

    insert: (obj: T) => string;
    asArray: T[];
}
```

The problem lies in the interface `Map<T>`. I would like the type of the actual map to be just `T`. I think the problem is that when `root.bar[x]` is requested where `x = insert`, the type of the returned object is `(obj: T) => string`. However, all keys in the map will be a string of length 8. What i'd actually like to do is something like this:

```
type ID = string[8]

interface Map<T> {
    [key: ID]: T

    insert: (obj: T) => string;
    asArray: T[];
}
```

I cannot figure out how to:

- create a type ID being a string of length 8
- use an alternative string-type as key (typescript will not allow me to)

I already looked in the typescript declarations file, where the Object type is defined. In this definition they seem to omit the map completely. Is this something that's implemented in the compiler/linter itself?

Does anyone know a fix or workaround to achieve something like this? I think it's pretty ugly to have to cast to a type T every time I do a map lookup.

Comment: *"...maps (objects) in..."* [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and objects are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

First, your use of the word `Map` is problematic since, as @TJCrowder mentions, that term [means something else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).  I will call your type `MyMap` in what follows.

---

TypeScript doesn't (currently as of v2.5) recognize any subtype of `string` corresponding to 8-character strings.  You can do this:

```
type Id = string & { length: 8 };
```

which defines a type `Id` as a particular type of `string`, but TypeScript is not clever enough to understand when a `string` is an `Id` (so it will never automatically narrow a `string` type to `Id`), and it will not let you use `Id` as the index type of an object.  If you want to make a `string` into an `Id` you will have to do it with a type assertion:

```
function toId(str: string): Id {
  if (str.length !== 8)
    throw new Error("an Id must have exactly 8 characters");
  return str as Id;
}
```

This might not be worth it to you.

---

Since TypeScript will not recognize the `Id` as an index type, there's no way to type `MyMap<T>` the way you want it: the index is a `string`, and so are `"insert"` and `"asArray"`.  The most TypeScript-friendly workaround (which plays nicely with the TypeScript type system and lets you reap its benefits) is to move the `Id`-indexed properties to its own object.  For example:

```
interface TSFriendlyMyMap<T> {
  props: { [key: string]: T } // can't do key: Id
  insert: (obj: T) => Id;
  asArray: T[];
}
```

In this case, you would use `props` to hold the properties.  Using the map would be a little different:

```
declare const reMap: TSFriendlyMyMap<RegExp>;
const id: Id = reMap.insert(/abc/);
const arr: RegExp[] = reMap.asArray; 
const regExp: RegExp = reMap.props[id] // instead of reMap[id]
```

but doesn't seem worse to me.

---

Another thing you could do is use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to make `MyMap` a callable *function* instead of an indexable *object*:

```
type CallableMyMap<T> = {
  (k: 'insert'): (obj: T) => Id
  (k: 'asArray'): T[];
  (k: Id): T
}
```

This behaves more closely to what you wanted, in that TypeScript knows that an `Id` yields a `T`, while `"insert"` and `"asArray"` don't:

```
declare const reMap: CallableMyMap<RegExp>;
const id: Id = reMap('insert')(/abc/);
const arr: RegExp[] = reMap('asArray');
const regExp: RegExp = reMap(id);
```

But you're using function calls, which is kind of weird.

---

I recommend `TSFriendlyMyMap` over `CallableMyMap`, and it's a tossup whether `Id` is preferable to just being careful with `string`.  But it's up to you.  Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!